# Inserting value into Excel cell instead of formula

Tags: excel, vba, cell-formatting

I have a VBA script that inserts long strings into Excel cells. In some cases, the string begins with a `=`. It seems like Excel interprets this as a formula and I get an `Out of Memory` error due to the memory limitations of formulas.

How do I tell Excel that I am writing a value, not a formula? Currently, I am doing this:

```
ws.Range("A" & row) = Mid(xml, first, CHUNK_SIZE)
```

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work...

```
ws.Range(...).Value = ....
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Append a `'` before the `=` sign:

```
Sub Test()

     'This returns 30 in cell Al
      Range("A1").Value = "=SUM(10,10,10)"

      'This shows formula as text in cell A2
      Range("A2").Value = "'" & "=SUM(10,10,10)"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an apostrophe `'` to the beginning of the string (that excel thinks is a formula) and excel should interpret it as a string instead of a formula.